# how do I get nginx to block a folder but a single subfolder?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

So what I have so far is this

```
location ^~* /sites {
   return 404;
}
```

which successfully blocks all urls that start /sites as I wanted. However I want to allow sites/all to not trigger this and I can't figure out how to do that regex. I tried a few variations but none worked. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
location ^~* /sites(?!/all) {
   return 404;
}
```

`(?!/all)` uses a negative lookahead to assert that the preceeding element is not followed by `/all`

Comment: That worked well except when I tried to expand it I had more problems. 

What I am trying to do is get files/ to redirect to sites/$host/files but don't want people going directly to sites/$host/files. They can only go directly to sites/all/files So I tried this

    location ~* /sites(?!/all) {
        internal;
    }
    rewrite ^(/files/.+)$ /sites/$host$1 last;

And they can get to sites/all. And they get blocked at sites/$host but they also get blocked at files/ as well. I don't understand why the last one is getting blocked as I understood internal would let it though?